# How to create htaccess 301 redirect to a new address with a hash in the url (to i.e. example.com/#clients)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I made a onepage site and now I want to redirect the old links to the homepage, and preferrably to the correct section.

How can I make a htaccess 301 redirect to a new address with hash un url (i.e. example.com/#clients)

Is it ok for search engines/google to have the hash? Does it matter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The hash part of a URL never reach the webserver. When the client browser sends a URL request to a web server it sends everything up to the hash sign, so you wont get the hash server side.

If you want to escape it in your redirect URL just use the NE flag appending [R=301,NE,L] to your rewriterule.

Answer (score 2):

On your old site put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newsite.com/#clients [L,NE,R=301]
```

Having `#` in URL won't cause any problem with your SEO ranking.

Answer (score 0):

I combined some tutorials and examples and got it working with this code:

```
RewriteRule ^en/contact.*$ http://domain.com/en/#contact [R=301,NE,L]
```

Which redirects from http://example.com/en/contact 
--->
http://example.com/en/#contact

It works.

But is this somehow different to anubhava's example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newsite.com/#clients [L,NE,R=301]
```